# Converting from parametric equation of cube face to general equation

Tags: parametric

I am trying to convert the vector equation:

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + 
s\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} +
t\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, 
s,t \in \mathbb{R}
$

which represents one of the faces of a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$, to general form.

I know that the general form is $x=0$, and parametric equations:

$x = s\\y = 0\\z = t$

But am confused how I might go straight to the general form from the parametric equations.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you should be getting $y = 0$, not $x = 0$, as the general form.

Comment: Right I see it now, that mistake was messing me up. Thanks.